# JMeter breakup of response time

Tags: jmeter

is there any way so that I can get the breakup of response time provided by JMeter. i.e.

- Travel time of total request
- processing time
- Travel time of total response

I know JMeter works entirely on client side, and the response is the TTLB. But any plugin or by any means to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking what you should know. 
There is no plugin which will give you such breakdown (getting processing time of server is impossible unless you have jmeter agents installed on target server. Monitoring agents are not part of Jmeter till now)

```
You can get approximate request travel time by using new Connect Time feature of Jmeter.
```

In practice,
Response time = processing time + latency

You can again find latency with multiple network tools or rough idea using ping (JMeter also gives latency. cross verify with ping or wanem)

```
Once you know latency you can get processing time.
```

I think you should get breakdown from this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a listener to the thread group：

jp@gc - Composite Graph

jp@gc - Connect Times Over Time

jp@gc - Response Times Over Time

2.jp@gc - Composite Graph  Configuration   Connect Times Over Time and Response Times Over Time

3.The result after running:

The larger the difference between the two listeners is, the bottleneck is at the network layer, and the smaller the difference is at the server layer.
[image]
4.You can also view specific data by adding a View Results in Table listener

Server processing time =Latency - Connect Time

The larger the difference is, the bottleneck is at the service layer, and the smaller the difference is, the bottleneck is at the network layer.

Server processing time covers program processing time, queue waiting time, database query time and so on. This method can confirm whether the bottleneck of response time is at the network layer or the service layer. If it is at the service layer, we may need to analyze further. So the term server processing time seems inaccurate.
[image]